# How to show arrows for backward (<) and forward (>) search

Tags: search

I had installed emacs and org mode in Fedora Linux and when I clicked the Search (magnifying glass icon) in the toolbar, automatically underneath the toolbar, an arrow button to search backwards (<), and an arrow button to search forwards (>), appeared.

I have now installed emacs in Rocky Linux, which is a fork of Red Hat Enterprise Linux. Rocky Linux was created as a replacement for Centos. Fedora is an upstream development distro for RHEL, so I thought emacs would be the same in both distros.

I have searched forums and the internet and package list for an answer and have not found anything.

How can I make those search buttons appear?
I was assuming there was some setting or package for this, but maybe that is not the case?

Comment: I don't know the reason, but I'll hazard a guess that this may be related to how Emacs was built: Fedora builds Emacs with the Gtk-3 toolkit. Others may use other toolkits and the appearance may differ. What distro did you install it on? Was it installed from a distro package or did you build it yourself? Please edit the question and add this information.

Comment: Hi NickD, thank you for your support once again :) You were instrumental in helping me get started with org mode over a year ago, and that is still very much appreciated. I will edit my post.

Comment: I tried on RHEL8 and I don't get those arrows, but the version that is installed is Emacs 26. Fedora 34 installs Emacs 27.2 by default which does have the arrows and I'm running emacs 28.0.50 which also has the arrows, but I haven't tried building a bleeding-edge Emacs on RHEL-8 to find  out whether the arrows are shown there; I suspect they would be. And my earlier hunch was wrong: the RHEL-8 Emacs is also built with the Gtk-3 toolkit. So my current hunch is that the Emacs version is too old.

Comment: Hi NickD, wow thank you so much for going thru the time and effort to try emacs on RHEL and Fedora!

Comment: I installed emacs 27.2 in Rocky using flatpak and as you found, this version does have the arrows. Unfortunately I get a warning in emacs saying the flathub version is unofficial. I will try to see how I can upgrade emacs 26 in Rocky Linux. Thanks again.

Comment: PS NickD would you like to provide your comment as an answer? I would be happy to mark it so....

Comment: If I figure out the reason that the arrows appear in 27 but not in 26, I might (assuming of course that that *is* the significant distinction). But bar that, it's only a hunch (and as we saw, hunches can be wrong ;-) ).

Comment: Hi NickD, a belated thanks (the site was in read only mode yesterday)